# TypeScript - rest operator behaviour not working when targeting es2018

Tags: typescript

This code works in the TypeScript Playground...

```
class Foo {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {

    }

    static make(...args: any[]): Foo {
        return new Foo(...args);
    }
}
```

[Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20make(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Foo(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

...but it doesn't work when it's in a TypeScript project in Visual Studio. I get the following error for `args` in the statement `return new Foo(...args);`

> Type must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an
>   iterator.

What's up here?

*Running TypeScript 2.7 on local machine. The problem occurs when I change the build target to **es2018***

Comment: Does your browser support es2018?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the compiler the default lib for `es2018` is incorrect. From compiler code at the time of writing:

```
export function getDefaultLibFileName(options: CompilerOptions): string {
    switch (options.target) {
        case ScriptTarget.ESNext:
            return "lib.esnext.full.d.ts";
        case ScriptTarget.ES2017:
            return "lib.es2017.full.d.ts";
        case ScriptTarget.ES2016:
            return "lib.es2016.full.d.ts";
        case ScriptTarget.ES2015:
            return "lib.es6.d.ts";  // We don't use lib.es2015.full.d.ts due to breaking change.
        default:
            return "lib.d.ts";
    }
}
```

The option for es2018 is missing. You can specify the appropriate lib manually:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2018",
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```